# how to validate a registration form in zend framework 2?

Tags: php, forms, validation, zend-framework2

i am trying to validate a user registration form in Zend Framework 2.

More specifically how to validate the email, ZF1 i could do:

```
$email->setValidators( array(new Zend_Validate_EmailAddress()) );
```

I'm wondering if i can just call something similar like this.

Also I'm wondering how to validate two fields that need to be the same like the password field and the password verification.

I guess that when i say `if($form->isValid())..` this will check the `getInputFilter()` method for all validation.

I've been taking a look at [ZfcUser](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser) module but, right now, i can't understand much since i don't have a full grasp on how ZF2 works

Any ideas, maybe a simple example?

thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you read the [official tutorial](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/overview.html) to see how the new ZF2 `Form` component works?

At a very high level, you need a `Form` object and a `Filter` object working together. The `Filter` object is where you place your filters and validators. However, if you use a form element of type `EmailAddress` in your `Form`, then it will automatically add the correct validator. There is more information in the [manual](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#validating-forms).

I recently did a webinar on forms for Zend which you should be able to find [on this page](http://www.zend.com/en/resources/webinars/framework).

Comment: Is there a difference between the usages of the components in ZF1 and ZF2. I mean, should we have to change the whole code if we need to migrate our app to ZF2?

Comment: @NandakumarV Refactor = very likely. ZF2 is a whole 'nother beast.

Comment: Certain bits are significantly different. Forms are one of those.

Answer (score 1):

i've figure it out.

the validators are multidimensional arrays and each array has a name and some options. It might be a bit wired in the beginning to notice it, but much configuration in zf2 is in this way

see an example for the password:

```
$inputFilter->add($factory->createInput([
            'name' => 'password',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => [ ['name' => 'StringTrim'], ],
            'validators' => [
                [
                    'name' => 'StringLength',
                    'options' => [
                        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
                        'min'      => 6,
                        'max'      => 128,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ]));

        $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput([
            'name' => 'password_verify',
            'required' => true,
            'filters' => [ ['name' => 'StringTrim'], ],
            'validators' => [
                array(
                    'name'    => 'StringLength',
                    'options' => array( 'min' => 6 ),
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'identical',
                    'options' => array('token' => 'password' )
                ),
            ],
        ]));
```

note, in php 5.3 > an array could be written like `array()` or `[]`, in the above example i mix them up for no particular reason.